# Two methods of finding a function $f$ such that $Mdx+Ndy=0$ on the curves $f(x,y)=c$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

this problem is from my class,i did one way and got one answer,professor did it in another way and got another answer.question is:Find
$f(x,y)=constant$ where differential equation is $$x(2x^2+3y^2-7)dx + y(3x^2+2y^2-8)dy =0$$
my professor did it in this way
[image]

[image]

and i did it in this way
[image]
[image]

There is no way these two function is equilant,so why did this happens?
Is there any problem with two solution,or  any logical problem??i doubt it may be a logical error in any of the one solution,please help me

Comment: You're better off typing those images up. The following should help with that if you're unfamiliar.
http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: You are better and smarter than your professor. Learn to wear your greatness with poise and tranquility.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution and answer are correct. Indeed, as soon as we see that $M_y=N_x$, the function $f$ is easier to determine the way you did.

**Aside**: being lazy, I do it with the following weird trick (calculus teachers *hate me*). Calculate 
$$
\int M\,dx = \frac12{x^4}+\frac32 x^2y^2-\frac72 x^2 \\
\int N\,dy = \frac12{y^4}+\frac32 x^2y^2-4y^2 
$$ and cook up $f$ by *merging* these formulas; not *adding*, but merging: meaning the repeated terms used only once. The resulting formula for $f$ indeed has $f_x=M$ and $f_y=N$, because $f$ is the first line plus something independent of $x$, and also the second line plus something independent of $y$.

The method used by the professor is valid in general, it does not require $M_y=N_x$. But the answer shown on your pictures is incorrect (I checked), but I did not feel like tracking down the source of the error.

Comment: i try to track error in first solution but i couldn't find.will you help me there?